Can't publish .NET9 MAUI Blazor Hybrid and Web App (new vs proj template)
MAUI-WITH-SHARED-PROJ
When I create a ".NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid and Web App" (new vs proj template), I am unable to publish the app.
Error message: The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win10-x64' is not recognized.
...\dotnet\sdk\9.0.100-preview.5.24307.3\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets  

I have read about the RID error and changed it to win-x64 but it does not fix the issue.
MAUI-STANDALONE
I am able to successfully publish a Maui windows app when I create a single project ".NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid"
If I add a shared project to the MAUI-STANDALONE, I get the same error.
MAUI-WITH-SHARED-PROJ
When I add
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>  

to this project I get this error
The RuntimeIdentifier 'win-x64' is invalid.
\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net9.0_17.2\17.2.9639-net9-p5\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets

Here is the pub profile for
MAUI-WITH-SHARED-PROJ
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishDir>bin\Debug\net9.0-android\publish\</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
    <TargetFramework>net9.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishSingleFile>false</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>false</PublishReadyToRun>
    <SelfContained>True</SelfContained>
    <PublishAppxPackage>true</PublishAppxPackage>
    <AppxPackageDir>C:\Work\</AppxPackageDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Here is the pub profile for
MAUI-STANDALONE
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishDir>bin\Debug\net9.0-android\publish\</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
    <TargetFramework>net9.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishSingleFile>false</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>false</PublishReadyToRun>
    <SelfContained>True</SelfContained>
    <PublishAppxPackage>true</PublishAppxPackage>
    <AppxPackageDir>C:\Work\</AppxPackageDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

